# Android: Populating a Table with an Arraylist from another Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist, tablelayout

I need to be pointed in the right direction here.

I've got an Arraylist(String) of names, and an Arraylist(String) of ratings. I want to display the names in column 1, and the rating values in column 2 in such a way that the user can see the name, and the rating they gave beside it in a tablelayout in the next activity.

The arraylists exist in the main activity, and need to be sent to the next activity, let's call it 'Activity Two'. Not sure how to achieve this with Arraylists.

So, basically. I need to know..

How to create a table layout column that will display the user entered data dynamically, and receives that data from an Arraylist in another activity.

Any advice is greatly appreciated my fellow Wizards.

Comment: I have my ArrayLists populated,I'm not sure if I should use intent to send the data, or if I should do something else. I assume there is a commonly used method for achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the information for your ArrayList and are simply calling a new Intent to open you should be able to pass this information in a Bundle to the new class. Since ArrayList implements Serializable you can pass the entire array to the new intent in a bundle and then load that in the new intent that you created.

```
    // Class that you have the ArrayList in MainActivity
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("NAME 1");
    names.add("NAME 2");

    ArrayList<String> ratings = new ArrayList<>();
    ratings.add("10");
    ratings.add("8");

    // Create the Bundle and add the ArrayLists as serializable
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("NAMES", names);
    bundle.putSerializable("RATINGS", ratings);

    // Start new intent with ArrayList Bundle passed in
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    intent.putExtra("KEY", bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Now that you have passed in the ArrayLists you need to extract that information in the new Intent that you called. This should be done in the onCreate of ActivityTwo

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_list_custom);

    // Get Extras that were passed in
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Not null then we can do stuff with it
    if (extras != null) {
        // Since we passed in a bundle need to get the bundle that we passed in with the key  "KEY"
        Bundle arrayListBundle = extras.getBundle("KEY");
        // and get whatever type user account id is

        // From our Bundle that was passed in can get the two arrays lists that we passed in - Make sure to case to ArrayList or won't work
        ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList) arrayListBundle.getSerializable("NAMES");
        ArrayList<String> ratings = (ArrayList) arrayListBundle.getSerializable("RATINGS");

        // TODO Make this do more than just log
        Log.i(TAG, "Name=" + names.get(0) + " Rating=" + ratings.get(0));
        Log.i(TAG, "Name=" + names.get(1) + " Rating=" + ratings.get(1));

    }
```

Comment: I love you, thank you so much for taking the time to clear this up @Trevor Will

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to simple write the data out to a SharedData.  Then you could call it back from any activity at any time.

I do this to have preferences set in one view that are then used later by a widget.  Same app.  Different views.  Same data.

To clarify:
I think I used to wrong term in saying SharedData.  What I really should have said was "SharedPreferences".

The way it works is, at some point in your activity, you write the data out.  You just tell it what values to write to what keys, and there it is.  In the background, the system stores an XML file unique to your app.  Once that file is there, any other activity in your app can call it up to retrieve the values.

The full explanation for this can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

I use this for an app where the actual main activity is a Widget.  The preferences for that widget are called up from SharedPreferences.  Those preferences are initially written in a normal full screen activity.  Once you set them, you close the activity, and the next time the widget updates, it grabs the current values.

Comment: what do you mean by a "SharedData", are you talking about using Intent or something else, now I'm trying to get the data in activity 1, to send to activity 3, and skip 2.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer here.  But I will update mine with a bit more info.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying!